# comparing one column to many and overwriting values with dplyr in r

Tags: r, dplyr

The concepts in r are easy to understand, but the syntax has been killing me. I have a column of values that I want to compare to the values in a range of other columns, and if a condition is met I want to overwrite the value in the column getting compared. I have to do this for hundreds of columns and thousands of rows and I can't get the syntax right to do the comparison to the range of columns. Here is an example:

```
base    a_01    a_02    a_03    a_04    ...     a_n
0.4        1       0       0       1              1
0.3        1       1       0       1              1
0.4        0       0       0       1              0
0.35       0       1       0       1              1
0.4        1       1       1       1              1
0.4        0       0       0       0              1
0.4        1       1       1       1              1
0.2        1       1       1       1              1
0.32.      0       0       1       1              0
0.4        1       1       1       1              1
```

Desired Output:

```
base    a_01    a_02    a_03    a_04    ...  a_n
0.4        1       0       0       1          1
0.3        0       0       0       0          0
0.4        0       0       0       1          0
0.35       0       0       0       0          0
0.4        1       1       1       1          1
0.4        0       0       0       0          1
0.4        1       1       1       1          1
0.2        0       0       0       0          0
0.32       0       0       0       0          0
0.4        1       1       1       1          1
```

So in the above example base is the column that I am comparing to each of the a_ columns. If base >=.4 and a_* is 1, then a_* stays 1 otherwise it goes to 0. I was trying to get it working with:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(across(contains("a_"), ifelse( ??? && base >= .4)))
```

that ??? just means I have no idea what to put there. There is probably an easier way to do it as well, but I am not an expert. I tend to stumble when trying to mass manipulate data.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we don't need an `ifelse`, create a logical vector with comparison operators and then coerce it to binary with `+` or `as.integer`.  The lambda function symbol is `~` and `.` represents the column values

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      mutate(across(contains("a_"), ~  +( .  == 1 & base >= .4)))
```

-output

```
#     base a_01 a_02 a_03 a_04 a_n
#1    0.4    1    0    0    1   1
#2    0.3    0    0    0    0   0
#3    0.4    0    0    0    1   0
#4   0.35    0    0    0    0   0
#5    0.4    1    1    1    1   1
#6    0.4    0    0    0    0   1
#7    0.4    1    1    1    1   1
#8    0.2    0    0    0    0   0
#9  0.32.    0    0    0    0   0
#10   0.4    1    1    1    1   1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(base = c("0.4", "0.3", "0.4", "0.35", "0.4", "0.4", 
"0.4", "0.2", "0.32.", "0.4"), a_01 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), a_02 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L), a_03 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), a_04 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), a_n = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't working. When I apply this to the original dataset all values are set to 0. The only difference between the example I posted and the real dataset (besides being much larger) is that it has other columns in it like time stamps and other things that aren't included in the across(contains()) call. That doesn't seem like it should affect anything? Could the . operator be including the other columns?

Comment: Also, is there a good page that explains the ~ in r? I can't seem to find anything

Comment: one more update as I played around with the original file. I went and deleted every other column so the only base and the a_' s were there. Only difference was that base was the last column instead of the first. Ran the code and still got the same result. all zeros even though there are plenty of true hits throughout.

Comment: another thing I tried ' mutate(across(contains("a_"), ~  +( a_1  == 1 & base >= .4))) ' just using a single column to check where things might be going wrong. Still 0s out that single column too.

Comment: Aaaaaaand never mind. the solution works brilliantly. I had a slight syntax error that messed everything up. Cheers!

Comment: @PlotDevice the `~` is a tidyverse shorthand for lambda function `function(x)`

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
df[-1] <- with(df,(base >= 0.4)*df[-1])
```

which gives

```
> df
   base a_01 a_02 a_03 a_04 a_n
1  0.40    1    0    0    1   1
2  0.30    0    0    0    0   0
3  0.40    0    0    0    1   0
4  0.35    0    0    0    0   0
5  0.40    1    1    1    1   1
6  0.40    0    0    0    0   1
7  0.40    1    1    1    1   1
8  0.20    0    0    0    0   0
9  0.32    0    0    0    0   0
10 0.40    1    1    1    1   1
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(base = c(0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.35, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2,
0.32, 0.4), a_01 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
    a_02 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), a_03 = c(0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), a_04 = c(1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), a_n = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-10L))
```

Comment: See my comment on the dplyr solution below. I also tried this one out. I got the following error 'Error in Ops.POSIXt(left, right) : '*' not defined for "POSIXt" objects'  I think this has to do with having the other columns I mentioned in the other comment. I need to exclude the other columns somehow and I am not sure how to do that

Comment: see other comments in the dplyr solution too. I stripped the file of all the other columns and tried this solution too. It resulted in no change. not sure why that would be.